# vstack rectangles left to right using open-cv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to vstack rectangles (from left to right) using open cv contour.

My images have a number of rectangles but the rectangles i'm interested in all have the same width.

In my sample image, I have 2 rectangles that have the same width and 3 rectangles that are irrelevant.

[image: Sample Image 1]
I have my MWE

```
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('1.png') # Read my Image
imgContours=img.copy() # Copy my Image for Contours
imgGray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Image to Gray
imgBlur=cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray,(5,5),1)  # Image to Blur
imgCanny=cv2.Canny(imgBlur,10,50)  # Image to Edges

contours,hierarchy =cv2.findContours(imgCanny,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(imgContours,contours,-1,(0,0,255),2)

# Find all my rectangles
rectangles=[]
for cont in contours:
    peri=cv2.arcLength(cont,True)
    approx=cv2.approxPolyDP(cont,0.01*peri,True)
    if len(approx)==4:
        rectangles.append(cont)

rectangles=sorted(rectangles,key=cv2.contourArea,reverse=True) # This is not reliable as my second sample image is not sorted from largest to smallest.

# Find corner points of my rectangle 1
rect_1_peri=cv2.arcLength(rectangles[0],True) 
rect_1_corner=cv2.approxPolyDP(rectangles[0],0.01*rect_1_peri,True)

# Find corner points of my rectangle 2
rect_2_peri=cv2.arcLength(rectangles[1],True) 
rect_2_corner=cv2.approxPolyDP(rectangles[1],0.01*rect_1_peri,True)
```

Desired Result:

[image: Output Image]

Test Image 2:
[image: Test Image]

I'd love some direction/strategy on how do I

a) identify from left to right the rectangles that have the same width.

At the moment, I can only identify them based on their areas but its not accurate.

I have attached my desired output for sample 1. I have also attached a test image to try the code for 3 different rectangles with the same width.

I hope this is clear.

Comment: Please explain clearly the problem. Is there an error? Where does it occur? The images must have the same width to vstack. So if they are not, one must be padded or cropped. Why are you using Canny?  What not just threshold the image to make a mask and use morphology to clean up. Then get the contours of the images. Then sort the contours by area. The get the bounding boxes from the contours. Then crop the two images. Then compare widths and pad or crop as appropriate. Then vstack.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand. Are these rectangles just drawings or are they photos? My comments above were about photos. But the same applies to simple rectangle drawings. Threshold on the background color and then invert so the rectangles are white on black background. Then get the external contours.

Comment: Hi @fmw42 I can get the contours of each individual rectangles but the problem I have is getting the contours of rectangles (one, two, three etc ) from left to right.

Comment: Filter out the unwanted ones by size. Then sort the bounding boxes by their x values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('1.png') # Read my Image
imgContours=img.copy() # Copy my Image for Contours
imgGray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Image to Gray
imgBlur=cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray,(5,5),1)  # Image to Blur
imgCanny=cv2.Canny(imgBlur,10,50)  # Image to Edges

contours,hierarchy =cv2.findContours(imgCanny,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
rectangles=[]
for cont in reversed(contours):
    area=cv2.contourArea(cont)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
    print("area=",area,"x & y =",x,y,"width & height6",w,h)
    peri=cv2.arcLength(cont,True)
    approx=cv2.approxPolyDP(cont,0.01*peri,True)
    if len(approx)==4:
        rectangles.append(cont)
        cv2.rectangle(imgContours, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow("con", imgContours)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

try this code to check the area,width and height of your required rectangles

```
output:
area= 107989.0 x & y = 19 18 width & height6 217 501
area= 89845.0 x & y = 281 20 width & height6 217 417
area= 29335.0 x & y = 623 77 width & height6 403 74
area= 18439.0 x & y = 688 184 width & height6 247 76
area= 6879.0 x & y = 749 291 width & height6 131 54
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
then try this code to select left to right
and auto set the width of the first left rectangle as a width of the program to find the same width rectangles

```
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('1.png') # Read my Image
imgContours=img.copy() # Copy my Image for Contours
imgGray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Image to Gray
imgBlur=cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray,(5,5),1)  # Image to Blur
imgCanny=cv2.Canny(imgBlur,10,50)  # Image to Edges
flag=0
width=0
contours,hierarchy =cv2.findContours(imgCanny,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
rectangles=[]
for cont in reversed(contours):
    area=cv2.contourArea(cont)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
    print("area=",area,"x & y =",x,y,"width & height6",w,h)
    peri=cv2.arcLength(cont,True)
    approx=cv2.approxPolyDP(cont,0.01*peri,True)
    if len(approx)==4:
        rectangles.append(cont)
        if w==width or flag==0:
            width=w
            flag=1
            cv2.rectangle(imgContours, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow("con", imgContours)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

output:
[image]
if you want you can crop out the area of the rectangle from the image

Comment: Hi @sourab maity, the code fails for my sample image 2 (test image) with 3 rectangles with the same width. I see that you hard coded the ```width =217``` but how are you teaching it to go from left to right?

Comment: how do i set the width of the first left rectangle without having to manually type in say 217?

Comment: Thanks for that, now I can go ahead and crop the images or warp it so that i can vstack them.

Comment: happy to help you